# Help with animation. Simulation ends prematurely. How to extend it?

Tags: animation, keyframes, soft-body

I'm currently working on a video featuring soft-body sphere "blobs", and I want to make the animation longer so I can see what's going on, but despite me extending the number of frames, the animation stops around frame 240. How do I make the animation last as long as I want to?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the *Physics* panel, under *Cache*, you need to increase the *Simulation End* value for each ball. If you want to change for all the balls at once, select them all, change the value and *Alt Enter*.

[image]